# Git log --graph --pretty=format: How to highlight unpushed tags?

Tags: git

I noticed that tags are displayed without any styling to indicate their possible states. They could be:

- lightweight or annotated
- local or both local and remote

In particular I'd like to get unpushed local tags highlighted for me in this git log graph view.

What would be sufficient is if tags could be shown with their origin prefixes, then I could look for any tags that are lacking that, to indicate they are local only and possibly need to be pushed.

If this is not possible, then I may have to resort to manually scripting a listing of unpushed tags via comparing `git tag` and `git ls-remote --tags` and jamming it in at the top of the `git log --graph --pretty` alias.

Comment: Git does not know whether or not a tag is present in the remote repository. This state is only known during a `git push` or a `git pull`, but is then lost as soon as the command ends. `git log` will be unable satisfy this part of your request.

Comment: I recommend `git for-each-ref refs/tags` over `git tag`. `git for-each-ref` shows if a tag is lightweight or annotated. For an annotated tag, `--format='%(objectname)'` prints the sha1 value of the commit object and `--format='%(*objectname)'` prints the sha1 value of the tag object.